# __slots__ and multiple inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I am doing a GSoC project that involves inheriting from two classes and I am running into the following error on account of both of the classes I am inheriting from having `__slots__` defined.

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

The easiest way I have found to solve this issue is to remove the `__slots__` declaration from either of the parent classes and move it into the child class. Unfortunately that means that my package would require including a modification of one parent classes in its distribution, which I would like to avoid. All of the solutions to this problem that I have found so far (on here and through googling) involve modifying a parent class. Is there a general solution to this that I have missed that can be done entirely with changes to the child class?

Comment: Do you really need to inherit from the problem classes? Usually, you can just screw inheritance and wrap them.